# check text entered inside a textbox is valid Dictionary word

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript

Hi I have a text box and button in html

`<input type="text">`

`<button>submit<button>`

when submit button is hit i want to check entered text is a dictionary word.

for ex:

if i enter

"SING" = VALID;

"SHNG" = Not a dictionary word.

Language used - ANGULAR 8 , CSS/SCSS, TypeScript,JavaScript

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

There is a library named **[Spell-checker.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/spell-checker-js)**.

You are using **angular**, so your are using **npm**. To install it run:

```
npm i spell-checker-js
```

You can use this code to work with library:

```
const spell = require('spell-checker-js')

// Load dictionary
spell.load('en')

// Checking text
const check = spell.check('Some text to check, blahblahblah, olololo')

console.log(check)
// -> ['blahblahblah', 'olololo']
```

Returns an array of not detected words in your passed text to `check()` function.

Note that if `check.length > 0`, it means you has misspell word(s) in your text.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Is there Any api which we can directly hit thorugh front end with out using backend Node, or java

Answer (score 1):

For every word in the dictionary, you will need a database or API to request and verify. But, if you have a limited list of words, try the array:

```
const words = ["something", "word"];
const exist = (words.indexOf("turtles") > -1); //return false or true
```